# Checking a Limit Proof

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, epsilon-delta

I have to prove that $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to c} \sqrt{x}=\sqrt{c},\;c>0, x>0$

So I have to show that given any $\epsilon>0$, there exists a $\delta>0$ that for all x in the domain $0<|x-c|<\delta$ implies $|\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{c}|<\epsilon$

So I have

$|\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{c}|=|x-c|/(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{c})<|x-c|/\sqrt{c}<\epsilon$,

So for any $\epsilon$>0, I let $\delta=\sqrt{c}\epsilon$,

So now

$|\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{c}|=|x-c|/(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{c})<|x-c|/\sqrt{c}|<\delta/\sqrt{c}=\epsilon\sqrt{c}/\sqrt{c}=\epsilon$

Does this proof work?

Comment: perfect.${{{}}}$

Comment: It does${}{}{}$

Comment: Thanks!  I just asked because my teacher posted a way longer solution online but this made sense what I did

Comment: How did you deduce the equality you used in your first step? It's not obvious to me

Comment: @GFauxPas: $(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{c})\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{c}}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{c}}\right)$.

Comment: @GFauxPas sorry I should've included that step, it's just that I typed all that on my phone which is very tedious so I just wanted to save some time.  Thank @Clarinetist!

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the comments, your proof is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I would use delta = minimum of your delta and c. This would force x to be positive and in the domain. (You wouldn't need to specify those conditions.)